# Does R language perfectly support cross platform running?

Tags: r

Is R language  a cross platform language? Means we can compile R lib in Linux x86_64  and using the compiled lib running in Linux PPCLE(PowerPC) .Does anyone encounter any issue when using the x86_64 build R lib running on the PPCLE(PowerPC) system?Or on what case the cross platform feature will fail on R ?

Comment: I've never seen a report of R running on a Linux PPC box. The only PPC R that I've seen was a Mac installation and that is extremely out of date now. I'd be happy to be corrected. The place I would research is the r-devel mailing list archive.